# LDPC in QKD difference from the classical context

Tags: error-correction, qkd

The usage of LDPC codes for error correction in Quantum Key Distribution (QKD) is very different from the classical use.

Say you have a word $\vec w$ that you want to transfer. In the **classical sense**, you encode it (usually by appending parity bits to it) by multiplying it with the generator matrix $G$:

$$\vec c = G \vec w.$$
Then, you can check the correctness of the received codeword $\vec r$ which might or might not equal the sent $\vec c$ with the parity-check matrix $H$. If $H\vec r \neq \vec 0$, you run the belief propagation, hopefully recovering $\vec c$.

In the **QKD** error correction, Alice and Bob have similar but in general not equal raw keys $R_A, R_B$. Alice uses the parity-check matrix $H$ of the LDPC code to compute the syndrome
$$s_A = H\cdot R_A.$$ She then sends $s_A$ to Bob and he uses it together with $R_B$ to run Belief propagation, which in the ideal case recovers $R_A$ from the fact that it should be similar to $R_B$ and the condition that it produces $s_A$ on multiplication with $H$.

Clearly, the approaches are very different - namely, the QKD usage never even needs the generator matrix $G$. Should the same LDPC codes be used in both contexts? Is an LDPC code that is good in the classical sense also good for QKD? Do all the LDPC constructions still yield good results? Is there any article that addresses these issues? I could not find any.